# how to set the expiry time more than 30 days in memcachedClient set() method

Tags: memcached, spymemcached

Is there any way to set the memcachedClient set(String key,int exp,Object obj) method to Store object more than 30 days(2592000 second).
If any then Explain please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can set the expiry as a timestamp.

According to the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewProgramming):

> Expiration times can be set from 0, meaning "never expire", to 30 days. Any time higher than 30 days is interpreted as a unix timestamp date. If you want to expire an object on january 1st of next year, this is how you do that.

Comment: i want to set the expiry time after sixty days. Like MemcachedClient client1 = new MemcachedClient(
    new BinaryConnectionFactory(),
    AddrUtil.getAddresses("172.22.65.111:11211")); .client1.set("key",2*60*60*30*24,"object"); but it doesn't work..can u please help me out

Comment: Get the current time in seconds since 1 January 1970 (usually your language will provide a `time` function that returns the current time in this integer format). Then add your 60 days (`time() + 60 * 24 * 3600`). That is your expiry in timestamp format.